# Traceback (most recent call last): File "/var/www/html/tki.py", _tkinter.TclError: no display name

Tags: python, php, html, python-3.x, tkinter

```
if (isset($_POST['D'])) {
echo shell_exec(" python3 /var/www/html/tki.py 2>&1");}

?>
<form method="post">
<button class="btn" name="D">DISINFECTENT</button><br><br>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

tki.py:

```
import serial
import time
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.configure(background="dark orange")
window.title("BASIC GUI")

megaBoard = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)

def motor_control():
    print(">>> XBEE + MOTOR CTRL - PROGRAM <<<\n")
    def forward():
        print("CTRL -> FORWARD + GREEN LED -> ON")
        megaBoard.write(b'a')

    def reverse():
        print("CTRL -> REVERSE + RED LED -> ON")
        megaBoard.write(b's')

    def quit():
        print("\n** END OF PROGRAM **")
        megaBoard.write(b'q')
        megaBoard.close()
        window.destroy()

    b1 = tk.Button(window, text="FORWARD", command=forward, bg="lime green", fg="gray7", font=("Comic Sans MS", 20))

    b2 = tk.Button(window, text="REVERSE", command=reverse, bg="firebrick2", fg="ghost white", font=("Comic Sans MS", 20))

    b3 = tk.Button(window, text="EXIT", command=quit, bg="gold", fg="gray7", font=("Comic Sans MS", 20))

    l = tk.Label(window, text="XBEE + MOTOR CTRL - PYTHON", bg="SlateBlue1", font=("Comic Sans MS", 15))

    b1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=10)
    b2.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=10)
    b3.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=5, pady=10)
    l.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=5, pady=10)

    window.mainloop()

time.sleep(2)
motor_control()
```

The python file when executed in terminal executes normally but the same file is link to a php button and it has to be executed on click of a button in my browser it throws an error.

error:

Traceback (most recent call last): File "/var/www/html/tki.py", line 5, in window = tk.Tk() File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/**init**.py", line 2023, in **init** self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use) _tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

Please do help.Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You are probably running your code in an environment, where window creation is disabled, are you controlling the remote server etc.? If so: window creation over ssh is disabled by default, see NullByte's video as a tutorial on how to enable it.

Comment: @БогданОпир no am running on ubuntu os...

Comment: It still seems to me like your window manager is inactive, Don't think I can help you, sorry